# Is it fine to use tasks and thread-pool together?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

After reading how the thread pool and tasks work in [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/brunoboucard/archive/2010/04/09/parallel-programming-task-oriented-parallel-part-1.aspx) article I came up with this question -

If I have a complex program in which some modules use `tasks` and some use `thread pool`, is it possible that there will be some scheduling problems due to the different uses?

Comment: I don't think so. Our big app uses all of them wildly together and we've never observed any issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. And there actually isn't much in the way of memory or performance inefficiencies when mixing approaches; by default tasks use the same thread pool that thread pool threads use.

The only significant disadvantage of mixing both is lack of consistency in your codebase. If you were to pick one, I would use TPL since it is has a rich API for handling many aspects of multi-threading and takes advantage of async/await language features.

Since your usage is divided down module lines, you don't have much to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Task are often implemented using the thread pool (one can of course also have tasks using other types of schedulers that give different behavior, but this is the default).  In terms of the actual code being executed (assuming your tasks are representing delegates being run) there really isn't much difference.

Tasks are simply creating a wrapper around that thread pool call to provide additional functionality when it comes to gather information about, and processing the results of, that asynchronous operation.  If you want to leverage that additional functionality then use tasks.  If you have no need to use it in some particular context, there's nothing wrong with using the thread pool directly.

Mix the two, so long as you don't have trouble getting what you want out of the results of those operations, is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, there wouldn't be problems - you just would be inefficient in doing both. use what is really needed and stick with the pattern. Remember to be sure that you make your app MT Safe also especially if you are accessing the same resources/variables etc... from different threads, regardless of which threading algorithm you use.

Comment: How do you mean it would be inefficient?

Comment: in the way things are constructed/managed/dealt with under the hood in the .NET Framework. And also because of code base management... would be a bit of a pain to maintain and be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any scheduling problems as such, but of course it's better to use Tasks and let the Framework decide what to do with the scheduled work. In the current version of the framework (4.5) the work will be queued through the ThreadPool unless the LongRunning option is used, but this behaviour may change in future of course.

Verdict: Mixing Tasks and ThreadPool isn't a problem, but for new applications it's recommended to use Tasks instead of queueing work items directly on the ThreadPool (one reason for that is ThreadPool isn't available in Windows 8 Runtime (Modern UI apps).